# DLL for Clave2 Basic is not supported by latest version of golang?

Tags: go, winapi, dll, ffi, cgo

We are trying to use Clave2 Basic senselock dongle to authenticate software. The software was written in Go 1.12 but when we updated Go version to 1.19 the build detects the DLL but is unable to call the functions.

Verify password function is as below

```golang
var error_message = []string{"EP_SUCCESS", "EP_OPEN_DEVICE_FAILED", "EP_FIND_DEVICE_FAILED", "EP_INVALID_PARAMETER", "EP_INVALID_BLOCK_NUMBER", "EP_HARDWARE_COMMUNICATE_ERROR", "EP_INVALID_PASSWORD", "EP_ACCESS_DENIED", "EP_ALREADY_OPENED", "EP_ALLOCATE_MEMORY_FAILED", "EP_INVALID_UPDATE_PACKAGE", "EP_SYN_ERROR", "EP_OTHER_ERROR"}

func VerifyPassword(password_type int, password string) error {
    password_ptr := (*C.uchar)(unsafe.Pointer(C.CString(password)))
    var result = C.LC_passwd(handle, C.int(password_type), password_ptr)
    if result == 0 {
        return nil
    }
    return errors.New(error_message[result])
}
```

If I run this function in Go v1.12 it works and returns result = 0, but if i try to run this function with same parameters in golang v1.19 I get result = 3, so it returns 'EP_INVALID_PARAMETER' string.

How exactly do I overcome this problem?

Comment: I am using the resources from http://senselock.com/en/productinfor.php?nid=214&id=177&pid=141 here

Comment: What is the function exported by the DLL that you're calling? `LC_passwd`? Can we see (parts of) the source code file which deals with its using? Is it linked in via `cgo` or does the code use `syscall.LoadLibrary` and friends?

Comment: yes its linked via cgo  
```/*
#cgo windows,amd64 LDFLAGS: -L${SRCDIR}/libs -lSense_LC_x64
#include "libs/Sense_LC.h"
*/
import "C"
```
have imported the header file and lib file, header file just contains function definations

Comment: Is it from `Clave 2 Enveloper_v1.0.0.0.zip` or `Clave2 Basic_v2.2.2.2.zip`? That "Basic" archive does not contain the "libs" directory—that's why I'm asking.

Comment: One more question: am I correct that you're building on `GOOS=windows GOARCH=amd64`, and for this platform (that is, no cross-compilation)?

Comment: I am using the basic archive `Clave2 Basic_v2.2.2.2\API\Win_x64\DLL` this folder has the dll and lib file, i have just created a libs folder in my structure

Comment: No i just want to build for one platform

Comment: @kostix, i contacted the senselock support and they sent me new dlls which work with latest version of go, thanks!

Comment: Glad you've have it solved :-)